# sumoselect is not working in angular 5 project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, multi-select, sumoselect.js

I have included the `[jquery.sumoselect.min.js][1]` file in the index file and using in ngOnInit function on one of the component as

```
$('.testselect1').SumoSelect({
      okCancelInMulti: true
  });
```

But it is throwing error like

> ERROR TypeError: $(...).SumoSelect is not a function

Do anyone know whats the problem is?

Comment: In general, JQuery plugins don't play nicely with Angular components.  The error you are getting seems to indicate that either JQuery or your plugin aren't loaded yet when this code is called.  You ***might*** be able to fix the problem by changing the load order of your scripts, but I don't really recommend it, since these two frameworks aren't really compatible.

Comment: if you **really** have no choice but to use sumoselect, you might try the Angular Wrapper:  https://github.com/ndxbxrme/ng-sumoselect